# Javascript executes just after second click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, toggle

I have not found neither a direct nor general answer to this problem but I believe there might be a general interest in solving it once and for all. I must admit I'm quite new to js.

My problem is, that I need to click twice on "link" to execute the javascript.

**head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(navi){
var elem = document.getElementById(navi);

if(elem.style.top == "-604px"){
    elem.style.top = "0px"; // elem.style.textDecoration = "underline"; 
}else{
    elem.style.top = "-604px";//elem.style.textDecoration = "none";
}}
</script>
```

**body**

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('navi')">Link</a>
```

A fiddle for better understanding: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQKQt/4/)

Maybe you can help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you were not passing a string into the 'toggle' function for it to select the element by it's id.

Then getting the CSS 'top' property using JQuery seems to solve the issue of 'elem.style.top' being empty on initialisation (requiring double click).

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkhBM/

```
$("#clicketyclick").click(function() { toggle("navi"); });

function toggle(navi) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(navi);
    //console.log(elem.style.top);
    //console.log($(elem).css('top'));
    if($(elem).css('top') == "-604px"){
        $(elem).css('top',"0px"); // elem.style.textDecoration = "underline"; 
    }else{
        $(elem).css('top',"-604px");//elem.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
}
```

console.log is extremely useful when debugging problems.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Also console.log is a great tip, haven't heard of that before.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to do this using jQuery, then you only have to click once:

```
<a id='clicketyclick'>Link</a>

<script>
    $("#clicketyclick").click(function() {
        toggle(navi);
    });
</script>
```

If you're new to JS you should learn jQuery, since it is one of the best javascript frameworks around, and it *will* make your life quite a lot easier.

If you,however, don't want to use jQuery, you could basically use:

```
<a onclick="toggle(navi)">Link</a>
```

Comment: Both the jQuery version and the js only version don't seem to work. I feel it has something to do with having the script executed when the DOM is ready instead of using an eventhandler to do so.

Comment: Have you included jQuery and set the link's id? Otherwise, could you create a fiddle?

Comment: I hope I implemented it correctly here, still doesn't work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQKQt/2/)

Comment: I see, make the toggle(navi) function like you did in your example, and call it using jQuery which can be done using `$("#clicketyclick").click(function() { toggle(navi); });` And then just make the toggle function somewhere else using: `function toggle(navi) { /*the function*/ }` That should fix your problem.

Comment: Hm I updated it as you said, but it still doesn't seem to work. Sure a beginner mistake I can't spot.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQKQt/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do as Max Langarek says or you could also just but click as a button instead of an a tag.

Maybe something like

```
<button  onclick="toggle(navi)">Button</button>
```

Either way, I've not seen the `javascript:toggle(navi)` way of calling a function before.. maybe I need more experience.

Comment: The javascript:toggle call is a direct linking call. Instead of placing a link there (http:// blablabla) you place the javascript call (javascript:) Which calls to the javascript on the same page. Although not frequently used, it is a viable way to call a function.

Comment: I guess I've not come across it yet... maybe I should try it out.. although I've not seen many good uses for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try counting your clicks

```
var clickNumber = 1;

function functionTwice() {

    if(clickNumber == 1) {
        clickNumber = clickNumber +1;
    }
    else if(clickNumber == 2) {
        clickNumber = 1;
            var elem = document.getElementById(navi);

    if(elem.style.top == "-604px"){
        elem.style.top = "0px"; // elem.style.textDecoration = "underline"; 
    }else{
        elem.style.top = "-604px";//elem.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
    }


}
```

HTML:

```
<a id='clicketyclick' onClick="functionTwice()">Link</a>
<div id="navi"></div>
```